# What is the correct way to implement PUT in REST?

Tags: rest, http, url, http-verbs

I can GET the data of a user on the /user/{username} URL and the reponse is

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "username" : "testuser",
  "email" : "test@example.org"
}
```

In my implementation if you PUT data on the /user/{username} URL the backend creates or updates the user with the specified username.

What is the correct way to handle that case when the backend gets a username in the URL like **/user/foo** and in the http payload as well like:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "username" : "bar",
  "email" : "test@example.org"
}
```

Should I return **409 - Conflict** or should I create or update a user with the username in the payload?

Comment: This question is a matter of opinion, so here's mine. You should not allow the same operation via two different actions. The way I would architect this is to implement PUT on /user for creating new users, and PATCH on /user/{username} for updates. No request should contain duplicate parameters, whether in the URL or HTTP payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In original [REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) concepts, URL should effectively be URI - resource identifier, that said, UNIQUELY identify your *user* entity in the system.

Thus, if in your model `username` is *unique* and it is not possible to have 2 users with same name, then you can use `username` in *resource identifier* URL.
Example - `/user/foo`

BUT, if it is possible that 2 users with different `id` can have same `username`, than according to *strict* REST you cannot use `username` as part of URL - it won't be REST anymore, just some web-service that accepts JSON in payload of PUT request.

Long story short:

1) If `username` is NOT unique identifier of user in your system - do NOT USE it in URL, use `id` instead, for example you've mentioned the URL will be `/user/1`

2) If `username` is UNIQUE identifier in your system - then you can have `/user/foo`.

============================================================================
In both cases you need to do integrity check that values in payload correspond to value in URL:
for 1) you check that `id` in URL is the same as in payload
for 2) you check that `username` in URL is the same as in payload

In case of inconsistency, I'd return status `HTTP 422 Unprocessable Entity` - *The request was well-formed but was unable to be followed due to semantic errors.*
Which exactly describes semantic inconsistency - structure of JSON payload is correct, but semantically `id` or `username` in URL and payload do not match.